# How to don't effect elements inside an filter-affected element?

Tags: html, css, filter, grayscale

I have a `<div>` on which I applied a grey filter, but all the other elements inside the `<div>` get affected by the filter, too.

Even if I try to override the elements by beeing more specific, 
e.g.

```
.div-id span { color: blue }
```

in the CSS didn't help me so far.

How can I solve this?

HTML:

```
<div class="idea-box-tools text-center">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span>
    <p class="box-headers">Dashboard & Tools</p>
    <p class="box-paragraphs">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.idea-box-tools:hover {
    background-image: url('includes/tools.jpg');
    background-size: contain;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(80%) brightness(20%) contrast(100%);    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't avoid it. Just as you can't with `opacity`.

What you can to however, making another `div` inside (with the background and filter), and display it below the other elements.

```css
.idea-box-tools:hover > :first-child {
  background-image: url('http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02690/Anne-Guichard_2690182k.jpg');
  background-size: contain;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(80%) brightness(20%) contrast(100%);
}
.box-headers {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="idea-box-tools text-center" style="position: relative">
  <div style="position: absolute;  height: 100%;  width: 100%;"></div>
  <div style="position: relative">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span>
    <p class="box-headers">Dashboard & Tools</p>
    <p class="box-paragraphs">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is exactly my problem. The red paragraph turns grey because of the filter.

Comment: Yeah, it works in this example. Not on my project. I can't work with position absolute.

Comment: Why not? Make sure you get the other positions right

Answer (score -1):

Something like this?

```
.div-id  { color: grey; } 
.div-id * { color: red; }
```

the * will match all elements beneath the div..